# Why does the static counter reset when changing a generic int to a string?

Tags: c#, generics

I am trying to learn the details of generics. Here is the example I am using. I am writing to the console the contents of a static counter for each class instance.

For a generic int, it works as expected. But when I change the generic to a string, the static counter is reset, why?

Thank you for any and all answers.

```
NamedContainer<Int32> a = new NamedContainer<int>(42, "The answer");  
                                                                      
Console.WriteLine($"NamedContainer calls: {a.Counter}"); //writes 1 to the console
                                                                      
var b = new NamedContainer<int>(99, "Number of red balloons");      
Console.WriteLine($"NamedContainer calls: {b.Counter}"); //writes 2

var c = new NamedContainer<int>(99, "Number of red balloons");
Console.WriteLine($"NamedContainer calls: {c.Counter}"); //writes 3 

var d = new NamedContainer<string>("Programming C#", "Book title"); 
//this resets the static Counter variable, why? 
Console.WriteLine($"NamedContainer calls: {d.Counter}");         
//writes 1 to the console, again why?


public class NamedContainer <T>
{
    static private int _counter;

    public NamedContainer(T item, string name) //The constructor for this Class
    {
        _counter++;
        Item = item;
        Name = name;
    }

    public T Item { get; }
    public string Name { get; }
    public int Counter { get => _counter; }
}
```

Comment: An instance property like `Counter` returning a static field like `_counter` should be a red flag and Visual Studio should suggest making `Counter` static because it doesn't use instance state. If you do that, then you'll need to use `NamedContainer<int>.Counter` and `NamedContainer<string>.Counter` to access it. That makes them look distinctly different, as they really are.

Answer (score 5):

`NamedContainer<int>` and `NamedContainer<string>` are two distinct types, therefore `NamedContainer<int>._counter` and `NamedContainer<string>._counter` are different fields.

If you want a single static field for both classes, derive them from a common non-generic class, e.g.:

```
public class NamedContainer
{
    static private int _counter;

    public NamedContainer()
    {
        _counter++;
    }

    public int Counter { get => _counter; }
}

public class NamedContainer<T> : NamedContainer
{
    public NamedContainer(T item, string name) //The constructor for this Class
    {
        Item = item;
        Name = name;
    }

    public T Item { get; }
    public string Name { get; }
}
```